# Can we 3-color a graph in polynomial time if we know the graph is 3-colorable?

Tags: algorithm, math, graph, graph-coloring

I understand that to decide if a graph is 3-colorable is NP hard. But I was wondering that, when we are given a guaranteed 3-colorable graph, can we 3-color the graph in polynomial time? 
Most of the resource I found are talking about deciding if a graph is 3-colorable... I am not sure what keywords I should put in google to get a better search result... So I am here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If we could, we would solve the NP-hard problem in polynomial time. Just run the polynomial algorithm while counting operations. If the limit is exceeded, the graph is not 3-colorable.

Comment: Thanks! That make sense....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching the web I found [this paper](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1083&context=cis_papers). Its authors prove that coloring a 3-colorable graph with 4 colors is NP-hard. That result carries over to bounded-degree 3-colorable graphs.

Since you mused about a suitable google search expression, mine has been

```
how to 3-color a 3-colorable graph
```